# In episode 1 of rokyubu, what is the manga that one of the characters is reading?

Tags: ro-kyu-bu

In episode 1 of rokyubu, what is the manga that one of the characters is reading?

[image: manga]

Comment: The only one I can think of with a similar art style is *Fight no Akatsuki*, but it doesn't seem to have similar characters. I'm thinking this might be a fictional manga. (PS: I uploaded another image of the inside, as well as the small cover images: http://i.imgur.com/9lTmMWy.png)

Comment: The character design almost looks like the one from *I'll*, but the jerseys are different. http://i.stack.imgur.com/pYcfb.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon closer examination, the manga she is reading is called *Shoot!!*.

[image: YAY FOR 1080P!]
<sup>(Click to zoom in.)</sup>

There *is* a real manga called *Shoot!*, but it is about soccer.

[image: Shoot! manga volume 21 cover]

So, the answer would be that she is reading a fictional basketball manga titled *Shoot!!*.

Comment: Impressive as always